# Understanding the pH scale for edible food!

Tags: ph, food-chemistry

I'm working on a website where I want to provide the pH level of plants! Although i don't even know what this is (I have zero knowledge in chemistry), I have to provide it! What I want to do is provide the pH spectrum on the website so that it would point to the correct pH level of a specific plant.

Let's use the following hypothetical examples from the database I was given:

- Peas:  preferred pH : **6.0 - 7.5**
- Beans  preferred pH : **6.0 - 6.8**

At this stage I want to point out that I'm only working with edible plants, vegetables, fruits etc.

Also here is a reference image that would be ideally used on the website:

[image]

From the image that was given above, I want to provide:

**1(One pH value) :** An arrow to point out the preferred pH of a plant.

**2 (Range of pH values):** an arc highlighting the range of the preferred pH of a plant.

---

**Questions:**

- Why is there a range in the preferred pH of a plant?
- Is it possible for an edible food to have a negative pH value? **Answer: NOT POSSIBLE**
- Is a pH level let's say 20 dangerous to consume (what is the minimum and maximum values that can be safely consumed)?

Comment: Negative pH is hardly ever encountered outside of a chemical lab, and pH 20 is physically impossible. Now to the point. You might want to know that pH is not just some arcane scientific quantity; no, it has a very common-sense, everyday meaning.

Comment: ....which is????

Comment: The measure of acidity, of course. Can you survive on a diet of lemons alone? Not for long, I guess. Well, that's the lower bound.

Comment: thanks @IvanNeretin ! It makes a lot of sense now! Now I have an answer to one of my questions

Comment: Beside that it is hard to find a sense on what you are asking and what you want to do, it is even unclear what is the pH "preferred by edible plants". Are you referring to the pH of the soil where they grow best, to the pH of the raw lymph, to the pH of the descending lymph, to the pH of the juice by pressing? All can be different. It smells about strange pH scales of food, lemon bicarbonate therapy and nonsense like that.

Comment: @Alchimista thanks for your reply, but I'm afraid I cannot answer that! I literally have no idea! I will have to contact the person that created the dataset!